# How to obtain macroscopic traffic measurements from flow-sumo?

Tags: sumo, traffic-simulation, flow-project

I am using flow with SUMO built-in environments such as the on-ramp merge network. I want to obtain macroscopic traffic measurements such as the density and flow of each edge/lane. Does flow output it? Or is there a way to add edge/lane-based outputs to SUMO configuration through flow?

I tried post-processing the emission data but they are vehicle data. It would be much easier to work with edge-based or lane-based data.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. is this?